# Defining Mutually Recursive functions in Coq

Tags: pl.programming-languages, coq

This question is related to (but not the same as):

[How to define a function inductively on two arguments in Coq?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/how-to-define-a-function-inductively-on-two-arguments-in-coq)

In particular, I used those techniques (defining a second fixed point function) and Coq still complains.

Consider the following formalization of regular expressions.

```
Inductive symbol : Set := Zero | One.

Definition string := list symbol.

Fixpoint symbol_eq (a:symbol) (b:symbol) : bool :=
  match a with
    Zero =>
    match b with
      Zero => true
    | One => false
    end
  | One =>
    match b with
      Zero => false
    | One => true
    end
  end.


Inductive regexp : Set :=
    Symbol (s:symbol)
  | Concat (r1:regexp) (r2:regexp)
  | Union (u1:regexp) (u2:regexp)
  | Star (u1:regexp)
  .

Fixpoint rgm (r:regexp) (s:string) :=
  match r with
    Symbol ss =>
      match s with
        nil => false
      | a::nil => (symbol_eq ss a)
      | a::b::tl => false
      end
   | Union r1 r2 => (orb (rgm r1 s) (rgm r2 s))
   | Concat r1 r2 =>
       let fix f s1 s2 :=
         match s2 with
           nil => (andb (rgm r1 (rev s1)) (rgm r2 s2))
         | a::tl => (orb (andb (rgm r1 (rev s1)) (rgm r2 s2))
                         (f (a::s1) tl))
         end
       in (f nil s)
   | Star r1 =>
       match s with
         nil => true
       | a::tl =>
         let fix f s1 s2 :=
           match s2 with
             nil => (rgm r1 (rev s1))
           | a::tl => (orb (andb (rgm r1 (rev s1)) (rgm r s2))
                           (f (a::s1) tl))
           end
         in (f (a::nil) tl)
       end
  end.
```

Coq refuses to compile it for the following reason:

```
Error: Cannot guess decreasing argument of fix.
```

Question: how can we fix this?

Comment: Do you know about `{struct x}` in `Fixpoint`? It tells Coq which argument it is decreasing. But more importantly, the recursive call `rgm r s2` is suspect. How can Coq tell that it won't loop forever?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Neither argument is always decreasing. We only know that some argument decreases every step. The (rgm r s2) step is okay because in "Star", we run (f (a::nil) tl) -- thus the length of the string is decreasing every time.

Comment: You don't have to explain this to me, but to Coq :-)

Comment: @AndrejBauer: I was hoping to use you as a English to Coq compiler.

Comment: While Andrej always gives good advice, I really have to suggest you take your question to the coq_club mailing list. You can even try to find a suitable answer in the archives: https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2012-03/mail2.html

Comment: The Coq `Program` facility is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297165/).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Coq Reference Manual](http://coq.inria.fr/V8.2pl1/refman/Reference-Manual004.html) (2.3)

> in Fixpoint, the decreasing argument must be given (unless the
>   function is not recursive), but it must not necessary be *structurally*
>   decreasing.

Key word is *structurally*, Coq can't guess, which arguments is decreasing at each step of the recursion.

The reason for this is nicely described in [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/Imp.html)

> Since Coq is not just a functional programming language, but also a
>   consistent logic, any potentially non-terminating function needs to be
>   rejected. Here is an (invalid!) Coq program showing what would go
>   wrong if Coq allowed non-terminating recursive functions:
>
> ```
>  Fixpoint loop_false (n : nat) : False := loop_false n.
> ```
>
> That is, propositions like False would become provable (e.g. loop_false 0 would
>   be a proof of False), which would be a disaster for Coq's logical
>   consistency.

Comment: Regarding your comment: "Coq can't guess, which arguments is decreasing at each step of the recursion." Not yet :) Me too I have access to some insider information and apparently it's a work-in-progress.

Comment: So it this behaviour will change in next versions?

Comment: Can't tell that, ask the dev team (http://coq.inria.fr/community).